# How to include current record in the resulting recordset when select uses graph projections

Tags: orientdb, orientdb-2.1, orientdb2.2

What is the **elegant** way to include a record in the set of records, when query uses a graph projection in the select?

For instance,

`select expand(both('friends')) from #123:456 limit -1`

The query above returns only adjacent vertices. How can I include `#123:456` into the resultset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select expand($c) from #123:456 let $a = (select expand(both('friends')) from #123:456 limit -1) , $b = (select expand(@rid) from #123:456), $c = unionAll( $a, $b )
```